# How to send form data from controller to connection file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express

I am trying to design login page using Angularjs and node.js and having error to send data from controller to my database connection file where I will perform transactions with database.

Error is POST http://localhost:63342/logindata 404 (Not Found)
and in description its pointing to line `$http.post('/logindata', $scope.user);`

[image]

Here is my code

Login.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="" ng-controller="LoginControl">

    User Name : <input type="text" ng-model="user.username">
    Password : <input type="password" ng-model="user.password">
    <br>
    <button ng-click='authentication()'>Submit</button>
</div>

<script src="myLoginController.js"></script>

</body>
</html>

</body>
</html>
```

myLoginController.js

```
function LoginControl($scope, $http){
    console.log("Hello...");

    $scope.authentication = function() {
       console.log($scope.user);

        $http.post('/logindata', $scope.user);
    };

}
```

connection.js

```
 var express = require('express');
 var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
 var app = express();

 app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/public/angular"));   
 app.use(bodyParser.json());

 app.post('/logindata', function (request,response) {
     console.log("received data");
     console.log(request.body);
 });

 app.listen(3000);
 console.log('Server running on 3000');
```

Anyone can please suggest me how to resolve this?
Thank you

Comment: what happens when you curl  http://localhost:63342/logindata ?

Comment: You can follow I am using simple insert query in table by using angular js . just follow the steps. http://php-tutorial-guide.blogspot.in/2015/09/ajax-form-submission-angularjs.html

Comment: @Sudhir I am not using PHP and I have read tutorials already. Can you please tell me whats going wrong in my code?

Comment: Controller send the date to specific files using $http.post( ) method. In connection file dp.php . It handle the request form method and perform database connection.

Comment: Or you can also follow this tutorial http://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2014/03/angularjs-workflow-in-webstorm/

Comment: I am doing same but in connection.js I am not getting logindata

Answer (score 0):

The server is running on port 3000, your request is to port 63342. That's the problem. The code itself is fine.

You should open your website at http://localhost:3000 and not the other port.

Comment: Instead I have changed my port to 63342 but still having same error

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it work in your dev environment, you can do the following:

1. Change the post URL in your controller to http://localhost:3000/logindata.
2. If you are using Chrome, add the extension - Allow-Control-Allow-Origin and enable it.

Your code should work now.

You are trying to do Cross Origin Resource Sharing(CORS) which is not allowed by the browser by default. The Chrome extension makes it work by adding required headers to the request.

Comment: Where should I add this extension?

Comment: To your Chrome browser

Comment: No, It doesn't work for me. Actually I am using WebStorm so I have changed my port to 63342

Comment: What is not working. You added the extension to Chrome?

Comment: Is the extension enabled? You should see the icon with green color next to the Chrome options icon.

Comment: Yes, I have that extension icon.